# Make a function run when a certain amount of time has passed with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I want to create a stopwatch with JavaScript, except when a certain amount of time has passed, a function runs, like an alert or something. The thing that I can't find on the web though, is that I don't want the text to show how much time has passed.

I've tried to go into some code and add if statements about when a particular time comes about, the function runs. But I haven't had any luck so far.

I don't have any example code files or anything like that because I've been testing loads of different ones.

So in the end, I don't want the stopwatch to show the text of much time has passed so far. I also want a function to run when a particular amount of time has passed after clicking the button. Hope somebody can help! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` and set the number of milliseconds you want to wait as below:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  alert('it works');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn’t think that it was going to work

Comment: try to avoid `setTimeout` as it's subject to lag, meaning if the application lags the timer will become inaccurate. You might want to look into the `Date` class.

Comment: Ok, will try as well